# Use definition of limit to prove $\lim(\ln(\frac{ne+1}{n}))=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

[Question is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpEJL.png)

Been learning real analysis lately and I never came across limits of logarithms or sin functions most limits are rational polynomials in text books so I wanted to try something else on my own, How would I start the proof of this? I just need a hint, I mean I applied the definition and I just can't progress at all. Is it the squeeze theorem?

I need to use the definition of epsilon $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ to find this limit.

Comment: Please do not post links to images. Put the equestions into your question. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ne + 1}{n} = e$

Comment: I will edit my question my deep apologies

Comment: Two hints: $log(a) - log(b) = log(a/b)$, and $log(e) = 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\ln$ is continuous

$\lim_{n \to \infty}(\ln(\frac{ne+1}{n}))=\ln(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ne+1}{n})=\ln(\lim_{n \to \infty}(e+\frac1n))=\ln e=1$

you can also use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition since

$|\ln(\frac{ne+1}{n})-1|=|\ln(\frac{ne+1}{n})-\ln e|=|\ln(\frac{1+en}{en})|=|\ln(\frac{1}{ne}+1)|$

$e^x>x+1 \Rightarrow x>\ln(x+1)$

$x>\ln(x+1)\Rightarrow|\ln(\frac{1}{ne}+1)|<|\frac{1}{en}|$

According to Archemedian Property there exist a natural number $N$ such that

$Ne\epsilon>1$

$Ne\epsilon>1 \Rightarrow\frac1{Ne}<\epsilon$

$n>N \Rightarrow |\ln(\frac{ne+1}{n})-1|<|\frac1{en}|<\epsilon$

Comment: How do I write this using the epsilon definition of the limit?

Comment: @Jos I have added epsilon-delta proof.

Comment: Oh wow I completely forgot that lne=1 I'll try solving it on my own now and compare my solution to yours, thanks a lot!